# Creating a layer showing difference before/after flood (raster)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, classification, imagery, differences, flood

I ran a supervised classification on two satellite images - (i) before and (ii) after a flood. Now even before the floods, there were pre-existing water bodies which obviously don't count as flooded areas.

I essentially want to cut parts of the *after_flood* classified layer based on the *before_flood* classified layer to create a new layer showing only the flooded areas from *after_flood*, while removing pre-existing water bodies from *before_flood*.

So far, I've extracted all 'water' cells and created two separate rasters (*before* and *after*), and have been playing around on those with some tools like Diff, Minus, etc. But none do what I need & I just can't figure out which tool/workflow to use.

I'm rather new to GIS, so maybe the solution is obvious because it seems like a pretty simple task. But I'm just not seeing it. How can I do this?

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.2

Comment: Hey thanks for flagging! Updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

So you have created two rasters the *before* and *after* flood event and you want to exclude in your *after* event raster all the pixels that were already water, as identified in your *before* raster.

Normally such rasters are binary, i.e. pixels that are 1 represent something, in your case water and zero means not water, in your case land.

If the rasters have the same spatial extent, cell size, number of rows/columns and are in fact aligned and land (i.e. not water) pixels are coded as zero then you could add them together, using the [Plus](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/plus.htm) tool. Logically anything that is 2 must have had water prior to the flood event. You would then use the [SetNull](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/set-null.htm) to set any pixels that are 2 to NODATA.

If your before and after rasters represent land as NODATA you could recode that using the reclassify tool.

Comment: I know it's a bit late, but I just got back to this project, did what you suggested and it worked like a charm. Thank you so much!! You're a gem.